# Formatting dates in IE and other browsers

Tags: javascript, date

I am using the following code to format my dates that come from the server to local dates:

```
var options = {
        year: "numeric", month: "numeric",
        day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
    };
    return new Date(Date.parse(date)).toLocaleDateString("en-us", options);
```

Works perfectly in Chrome, but not so good in IE or Firefox.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz5nLL6L/1/)

Thanks for help.

Comment: What versions of IE and Firefox?  Not all versions [support the parameterised version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Browser_compatibility) of `toLocaleDateString`.  Also note that `new Date(Date.parse(...` is redundant - the date constructor will internally call `Date.parse` if it needs to.

Comment: Latest IE on Windows 7.

Comment: That only works for browsers that support the ECMA-402 Internationalization API. Otherwise, the parameters are ignored. Not supported in Safari either.

Comment: What is the format of *date*? Using the Date constructor to parse strings is extremely unreliable, you might find it much simpler to just reformat the original string.